# $ABCD$ is a rectangle with $AD = 2$ , $AB = 4$. $P$ is on $AB$ such that $AP : PB = 2 : 1$. $CE \perp DP$ at $E$. Find $CE$.

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, contest-math, problem-solving, polygons

> $ABCD$ is a rectangle with $AD = 2$, $AB = 4$. $P$ is on $AB$ such that $AP : PB = 2 : 1$. $CE \perp DP$ at $E$. Find $CE$.

**What I Tried**: Here is a picture :-

[image]

Since $AP : PB = 2 : 1$ and $AB = CD$, we have $AP = \frac{8}{3}$, $BP = \frac{4}{3}$.

Now :- $$[\Delta DPC] = \frac{[\square ABCD]}{2}$$
$$\Rightarrow [\Delta DPC] = 4$$

From Pythagoras Theorem :- $$(AP)^2 + (AD)^2 = (PD)^2$$
$$\Rightarrow PD = \frac{\sqrt{82}}{3}$$

So, $$[\Delta PDC] = \frac{1}{2} * PD * CE$$
$$\Rightarrow 4 = \frac{1}{2} * \frac{\sqrt{82}}{3} * CE$$
$$\Rightarrow CE = \frac{12 \sqrt{82}}{41}$$

But my answer was given as $\frac{12}{5}$ , so where did I go wrong? 
Can anyone help me? Thank You.

Comment: On your drawing P is not on AB

Comment: Oh my bad, $P$ and $E$ should interchanged .

Comment: In that case the answer should be clear by considering areas

Comment: Not just that, AP:PM doesn't seem to be 2:1. All in all you should make a new drawing, that might help.

Comment: Ok I made some terrible mistakes in my drawing. I also forgot the fact $AP : PB = 2 : 1. $ I would not have taken $x$ and $(4 - x)$ then.

Comment: I made a large modification right now. Please see it.

Comment: You just miscalculated the length of PD (you forgot to square AD); it should be $\frac{10}{3}$; replacing that value in your final calculation will give the correct answer.

Comment: I just saw the last comment. Yes there was nothing wrong with your approach. Just a calculation mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$PD=\color{red}{\dfrac{\sqrt{82}}{3}}$ is false.

$$AD=\dfrac{\color{blue}{6}}{3}, AP=\dfrac{\color{blue}{8}}{3} \Rightarrow PD=\dfrac{\color{blue}{10}}{3}$$